# Can't understand Output shape of a Dense layer - keras

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I am following an online tutorial to classify images and started off with dense layers as a starting point to classify cifar10 data.

```
# Create a model and add layers
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

# Print summary
model.summary()
```

[image]

`dense_1 output shape (None, 32, 32, 512)`. 'None' represents the batch size, but what does '32,32' represent? Why isn't the shape (None, 512)? Same happens with the dense_2 layer.

Can someone explain it here or point me to a resource that explains this?

Comment: This [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747343/keras-input-explanation-input-shape-units-batch-size-dim-etc) to this question may help you understand the concepts of units, input and output shapes, in Keras layers.

Answer (score 5):

Keras is applying the dense layer to each position of the image, acting like a `1x1` convolution.

More precisely, you apply each one of the 512 dense neurons to each of the `32x32` positions, using the 3 colour values at each position as input. That's why you have `512*3 (weights) + 512 (biases) = 2048 parameters`.

As a consequence, for each neuron in each position you generate an output, and that's why you have 512 outputs for each position, i.e., `32x32x512`.

This all happens for each example in the batch: that's the `None` part.

Answer (score 5):

So to my understanding, *Dense* is pretty much Keras's way to say *matrix multiplication*.

**SUMMARY:**

Whenever we say `Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3))`, what we are really saying is **Perform matrix multiplication to result in an output matrix with a desired last dimension to be *512***.

What gets lost in translation is that the ***512*** is just **ONE** part of the desired output, not the whole picture.  Keras sees the input shape and the Dense shape and automagically figures out that you want to perform the matrix multiplication.

---

**EXAMPLE 1:**

Let's look at `Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3))`.

**Matrix multiplication:**

```
(None, 32, 32, 3) * (3, 512)
```

**EXPLANATION:**

1. `None` is the number of pictures determined at model training, so it doesn't matter right now.
2. `(..., 32, 32, 3)` is the `input_shape` specified in the `Dense(...)`
3. `(3, 512)` comes from Keras seeing that you have the last dimension as a `(..., ..., ..., 3)` as your `input_shape`. So Keras takes that last `3` and combines that with the `512` to result in the final shape of `(3, 512)`.  Taa-daa, automagic explained.

**Results in:**

```
(None, 32, 32, 512)
```

This is because those two `3`s cancel each other out because of the matrix multiplication.

The `Param #` comes from `(3 * 512) + 512 = 2048` as pointed out by grovina's answer.  This is because of this equation:

`input * weights + bias`

1. `input` would be the `3` (aka number of params per neuron)
2. `weights` would be the `512` (aka number of neurons)
3. `bias` would be the `512` (aka one bias per neuron)

---

**EXAMPLE 2:**

Let's do the same with the `Dense(10, activation='softmax')`.

**Matrix multiplication:**

```
(None, 32, 32, 512) * (512, 10)
```

**EXPLANATION:**

1. `None` doesn't matter right now.
2. `(..., 32, 32, 512)` is the `input_shape` that comes from the first `Dense(...)`
3. `(512, 10)` comes from the last dimension of the `input_shape` and the `10` specified in the second `Dense(...)`

**Results in:**

```
(None, 32, 32, 10)
```

The two `512`s cancel out.

`Param #` is `(512 * 10) + 10 = 5130`

1. `input` would be the `512` (aka number of params per neuron)
2. `weights` would be the `10` (aka number of neurons)
3. `bias` would be the `10` (aka one bias per neuron)

Answer (score 2):

Right. What are the attributes of your input layer? Unless I am mistaken, you have not flattened your image at all. So you have sent a 32 x 32 image directly to a dense layer, and not a convolutional layer. (As a side note, it could be that you are following a very bad tutorial, as this is not what good tutorials do).

What you can do instead, if you are trying to compare the performance of a network with out convolutions to one with convolutions, is [flatten the images](https://keras.io/layers/core/#flatten).

Then, run these two dense layers. Can you share which tutorial you are following?
When I studied DNNs in school, we used this [online textbook](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html).

It was written before Keras (or Tensor-flow, MXNet, anything) so it does not have Keras examples. But, between the Keras documentation, this book, and this forum, you should be able to grasp Deep Learning.

Comment: If you flatten the images, doesn't this mean that 2D Conv layers wont work properly?